# Get the value of variable when it's not null

Tags: java, oop

I need to get value of password variable from PasswordFrame in my Main class when it is not `null`. Here is code of PasswordFrame:

```
public class PasswordFrame extends JFrame {
    static JTextField tf;
    static JButton button; 
    public String password;
    boolean isPassword = false;
    public PasswordFrame(){
        tf = new JTextField();
        button = new JButton("Enter");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                password =  tf.getText();
                isPassword = true;
            }

        });
    }
```

I already have tried do it using this code:

```
public String getPassword(){
        while(!(isPassword)){
        }
        System.out.println("out");
        return password;
    }
```

But when I tried

```
PasswordFrame  passwordfield = new PasswordFrame();
if (password.equals(passwordfield.getPassword())){
//code
}
```

"out" isn't printed and it can't exit `while` loop. Why? And how can I make PasswordFrame work correctly and return password.

P.S. If you're going to downvote , tell me what can I improve to make my question more clear.

Comment: Your while loop is empty. If it never changes its condition, how can it ever terminate?

Comment: `boolean isPassword` should be volatile

Comment: @azurefrog but condition will be changed when I press "Enter" button. Right?

Comment: That depends on where and how you are defining and calling `getPassword()`.  What is that method supposed to do, and how are you using it?

Comment: Not sure I understand the point of `getPassword`.  Do you really want to block the thread in a tight loop until the password is entered?  It seems like you should have some sort of event that gets fired when a password is available, and external code should listen on that event.

Comment: can you also share how are you calling that getPassword function

Comment: @Mike Christensen no, I don't need to block thread in loop but I thought that is the only way to wait until password is entered.

Comment: your getPassword method should use the reference you created (passwordfield) to find the value.  Something like while (!(passwordfield. isPassword))

Comment: @Lashane yes, you're right. It's definitely what I desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boolean isPassword` should be replaced with `volatile boolean isPassword`(according to @Lashane 's comment) to show that different threads can change this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class PasswordFrame extends JFrame {
static JTextField tf;
static JButton button; 
public String password;
boolean isPassword = false;
public PasswordFrame(){
    tf = new JTextField();
    button = new JButton("Enter");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        password =  tf.getText();
            /* 
             * Check for non-null password must check both 
             * conditions ion this order
             */
            if(if(password != null && ! password.isEmpty()){
               isPassword = true;
            }
        }

    });
}
```